# Customer address update code is always creating new address

Tags: customer-address

I am facing a strange behavior in the following code (Magento EE 1.14.2.0). Though it's an update code as it's being loaded by ID, it's always creating a new entries.

```
$customerId = 123;
$addressId  = 123;

echo '<hr />';
echo 'Loading address::' . $addressId . '<br />';
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$address->load($addressId);
$addressData = array (
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'street' =>
        array (
            0 => 'street 1',
            1 => 'street 2',
        ),
    'telephone' => '+1-000000',
    'postcode'  => 'xxx',
    'city'      => 'NY',
    'region'    => 'NY',
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname'  => 'Doe',
);

$address->setData($addressData);
$address->setCustomerId($customerId);
$address->save();
echo '<hr />';
Zend_Debug::dump(
    $address->getData()
);
```

I checked Customer Address Api & My Account Address section, they are also using the similar code.

Do you guys see any issue with the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$address->addData($addressData)` instead of `$address->setData($addressData)` since `setData` will overwrite all the data in the object, including `entity_id`.

Comment: My bad :) I was too fast to post the Question. Either `setData($key, $value)` or `addData($array)` fixes the issue.

Comment: @MagePsycho OR use $address->setData($addressData)->setId($addressId)->save();